# Regex to replace a string containing variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, xpath

I'm new to regex. I got a prob here. I work with xpaths strings. I want to remove a particular element from xpath string if the element has `id = myVar`

Example:

`/html/body/div[3]/div[20]/section[1]/p[5]/span[1][@id="var645932"]/span`

I want to replace the `/span[1][@id="var645932"]/` with just `/` if my variable value is equal to id value i.e `var645932`

I need to do it in javascript. all are strings. I prefer regex. if any regex experts are there Kindly help. am stuck here. is it possible to accomplish it without regex ??

Any help are highly appreciated :) TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var input = '/html/body/div[3]/div[20]/section[1]/p[5]/span[1][@id="var645932"]/span';
var regex = /\w+\[\w+\]\[\@id="var645932"\]\//gi;
input = input.replace(regex, '');
console.log(input);
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gzr8g8f6/)

This regex is designed to work even if the structure of the HTML changes, eg:

```js
var input = '/html/body/div[3]/div[20]/section[1]/div[6][@id="var645932"]/span';
```

If you need to set the `id` in the regex programmatically, use this:

```js
var regex = new RegExp('/\w+\[\w+\]\[\@id="' + id + '"\]\//', 'gi');
```

Comment: this is exactly wat I needed. But How to pass the variable instead of hardcoding

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code -

```
var expr = '/html/body/div[3]/div[20]/section[1]/p[5]/span[1][@id="var645932"]/span';
var idVal = "var645932";
expr = expr.replace('span[1][@id="'+idVal+'"]/','');
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/m3wba0La/)**

Comment: ok, then you should follow Rory's answer and concatenate variable in the middle of regEx as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do it in the following way

```
var id = "var645932";
var regx = new RegExp('/[^/]+?\\[@id="' + id + '"]/');
var str = '/html/body/div[3]/div[20]/section[1]/p[5]/span[1][@id="var645932"]/span';
console.log(str.replace(regx, "/"));
```